# DDS Time vs. DDL Time

Tags: c#, datetime, time, db2, ibm-midrange

I am working through an issue here. I have a C#.NET application that is uploading data to the i. In one application, I have the file defined as DDS (old habits don't die) with a time field. In this new application, I am using DDL to create the file and it also has a time field. I have basically copied and pasted the line from the working application to the new application and still doesn't work. The only difference I can see is DDS vs. DDL. Is anyone able to confirm there is some sort of difference (even though I don't know why there wold be)?

DDL:

```
CREATE TABLE EGOVLOG.TRANYYMMDD ( 
    ...
    PAYMENTDATE FOR COLUMN PAYDATE DATE NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_DATE , 
    PAYMENTTIME FOR COLUMN PAYTIME TIME NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIME , 
    ...     
        PRIMARY KEY( ID ))
        RCDFMT TRANYYMMDD;
```

DDS:

```
 A            RSSIGNDATE      L         ALIAS(SUPERVISOR_SIGNED_DATE)
 A                                      COLHDG('SUPERVISOR' 'SIGNED DATE')
 A                                      TEXT('SUPERVISOR SIGNED DATE')
 A            RSSIGNTIME      T         ALIAS(SUPERVISOR_SIGNED_TIME)
 A                                      COLHDG('SUPERVISOR' 'SIGNED TIME')
 A                                      TEXT('SUPERVISOR SIGNED TIME')
```

Working line:

```
// Outputs "15.21.47"
cmd.Parameters.Add("@SUPERVISOR_SIGNED_TIME", iDB2DbType.iDB2Time).Value =
    leaveRequest.SupervisorSignedDateTime.ToString("HH.mm.ss");
```

Non-working line:

```
// Outputs "15.21.47"
cmd.Parameters.Add("@PAYMENTTIME", iDB2DbType.iDB2Time).Value =
    transactions.Transaction.TransactionTimestamp.ToString("HH.mm.ss");
```

Both `leaveRequest.SupervisorSignedDateTime` and `transactions.Transaction.TransactionTimestamp` are of the same C# type (`DateTime`).

The error is:

> IBM.Data.DB2.iSeries.iDB2ConversionException was unhandled
>
> Message=A conversion error occurred.
>
> Source=IBM.Data.DB2.iSeries
>
> MessageCode=111
>
> MessageDetails=Parameter: 13.

**Update:** To add to the mystery, I ran the insert manually, this works.

```
INSERT INTO TABLE VALUES(...'10/19/2011', '15:21:47', ...)
```

Comment: Is `TransactionTimestamp` really a `DateTime` or is it a `TIMESTAMP` field (i.e. a row-based version identifier)?

Comment: In the stored procedures you are calling, are both SUPERVISOR_SIGNED_TIME and PAYMENTTIME the exact same data type?

Comment: @Yuck It was a bad name choice for me... `TransactionTimestamp` is `DateTime`.

Comment: @Chris Lively No stored procedures, straight SQL insert.

Comment: Could we get: The outputs of the `ToString` method, as well as the relevant DDS and DDL lines, please?

Comment: Well, that is confusing; from what I know they should be the exact same thing, and DB2's `TIME` function can cast that string easily.  The only thing I can think of is if the parameter is somehow expecting a differently formatted time to be incoming; will it accept differently formatted time, input manually? Oh - generally you're not going to want seperated date/time values like this, you're going to want an actual timestamp - the two values are only useful (and potentially valid) when combined.  (And are you sure that the 13th parameter?)

Comment: @X-Zero I thought about Timestamp, but that is a royal pain to query for on the i side. And the senior RPG developer already complains about a date field.

Comment: @Mike Ive never had any issue with timestamps in RPG... You did notice that time is in a different format, right - Although I don't think that should make a difference (it should convert them both, regardless).  Maybe the TIMFMT or TIMSEP parameters are causing the `Parameter` setter to throw an exception?  And if he's complaining about size, that's usually a _far_ more trivial issue than having to deal with the headache of separate fields.  Please tell me you usually use an actual date field, and aren't hanging onto 7P dates wherever possible...

Comment: I tried both : and . in my code and neither worked. Sorry, I didn't
explain that further.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was the order of my parameters and/or the format of the date.

I also changed the code noted above to:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@PAYMENTDATE", iDB2DbType.iDB2Date).Value = transactions.Transaction.TransactionTimestamp.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
cmd.Parameters.Add("@PAYMENTTIME", iDB2DbType.iDB2Time).Value = transactions.Transaction.TransactionTimestamp.ToString("HH.mm.ss");
```

Comment: Please edit your answer to make it more obvious that the `date` parameter needed to be specified first, then the `time`.  If possible (and it exists), it would be a better answer if you could find a reference in the manual to this behaviour (for future questioners with this same problem).  It should maybe be noted that this seems to be a C# _library_ issue, not a DB2 issue directly.